# After installing a new sound card, my BIOS drives me crazy

Tags: bios, sound-card

I diconnected the AC'97 front panel header from the mobo and connected it to the sound card.
The front panel audio works, i.e. after connecting it to the new sound card, the mic and headphones I connected to it work fine.

I have absolutely no problems (hardware or software), driver issues, or even boot errors, and everything is perfectly fine. I just get a "Press F1 to boot" prompt that always says "Front panel audio not connected". How do I get rid of this **annoying** message (and prompt)?

I have an HP Compaq DC7100 CMT and an Asus Xonar DG sound card. I have the latest BIOS version ([2.14A](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=473284&prodTypeId=12454&prodSeriesId=402163&swEnvOID=1093&taskId=135&swLang=8)) but don't know how to "fix" this. Anyway, [here's technical info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHuDL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you don't have anything connected to the motherboard's front panel sound connector.

You should be able to fix it by disabling the motherboard's sound card in the BIOS.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I did that, but it won't work.